# callback problem - callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, express

I got an error like that: uncaughtException TypeError: cb is not a function
I think this error is caused by callback error but I don't know why I have this error.

```js
app.put('/badge/student_badge/:id', upload, (req, res, next) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  let data = {
    name: name
  }
  badger.updatePersonBadge({
    id: req.params.id
  }, data, (err) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Post updated successfully!'
    });
  });
});

function updatePersonBadge(options, cb) {
  schemas.badger.then(b => {
    b.findById({
      _id: options.id
    }, (err, resp) => {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      if (!resp) return cb("no badge found");
      name = options.name;
      title = resp.title;
      points = resp.points;

      updateBadge(name, title, points, cb);
      cb(null, resp);
    })
  })
}

function updateBadge(name, title, points, cb) {
  const dateCreated = new Date(),
    dateUpdated = dateCreated;
  registerSchemas.personModel.then(p => {
    p.findOneAndUpdate({
      name: name
    }, {
      $push: {
        badges: [{
          title: title,
          points: points,
          dateCreated: dateCreated,
          dateUpdated: dateUpdated
        }]
      }
    }, (err, resp) => {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      if (!resp) return cb("no person found");
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling updatePersonBadge with a function as a second argument

Comment: include the code where you are calling the updatePersonBadge function

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `cb` argument and if it's optional (at least seems it should be) the function misses an `if` statement:

```
updatePersonBadge(options, cb) {   // << cb (callback) argument expected

  // ...
  cb(null, resp);    // cb called therefore not optional (Its needed)
```

If you use it like `updatePersonBadge(aaa)` instead of `updatePersonBadge(aaa, myCallbackFn)` the `cb()` is `undefined` but expressed as a function call - that does not exist.

You could instead make it optional (if that's the case):

```
  //...
  if(cb) cb(null, resp); // call the cb function if cb argument exists
```

or if you want to be more specific:

```
  //...
  if(cb && typeof cb === 'function') cb(null, resp);
```

instead of passing a function you're passing `data`:

```
badger.updatePersonBadge({}, data, errFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the place from where you are calling updatePersonBadge. IF yes, then you are passing callback as a third argument, You have to use them correctly.

```
badger.updatePersonBadge(
{
   id: req.params.id
}, 
data,
(err) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.status(201).json({
       message: 'Post updated successfully!'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example the problem is parameter mismatch, In place of callback you send data

```
app.put('/badge/student_badge/:id', upload, (req, res, next) => {
const name = req.body.name;     
let data = {
    name: name
}
badger.updatePersonBadge({id:req.params.id}, data, (err)=>{.   -- three arguments passed
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Post updated successfully!'
    });
});
```

});

Where in function definition you have only 2 parameters defined.
where it should be 3 parameters / that particular scenario should be validated.